How to extract Standard Error Estimates as well as AIC and BIC from fit using extRemes.fevd() in R?
GEV fit:
library(extRemes)

# fake data
data <- data.frame(years = 1950:2023, values = runif(74))

# fit GEV model
model <- fevd(values, data, unit = "mm", type = "GEV", method = "MLE")

# extract parameters
parameters <- model$results$par
loc <- parameters[["location"]]
scale <- parameters[["scale"]]
shape <- parameters[["shape"]]

After fitting the Generalized extreme value distribution, I want to store the parameters, the standard errors of the parameters as well as the AIC and BIC metric as numeric values.
I am able to store the parameters, but can't find the errors and AIC/ BIC values in the model instance.
# extract Standard Error Estimates
loc_se <-
scale_se <- 
shape_se <-

# Extract AIC and BIC
aic <-
bic <-

I appreciate any help!

It is possible to extract the Standard Error Estimates and the AIC/ BIC values from summary(model). But for that the summary will be printedi in the Console.
library(extRemes)

# fake data
data <- data.frame(years = 1950:2023, values = runif(74))

# fit GEV model
model <- fevd(values, data, unit = "mm", type = "GEV", method = "MLE")

# extract parameters
loc <- model$results$par[["location"]]
scale <- model$results$par[["scale"]]
shape <- model$results$par[["shape"]]

# extract Standard Error Estimates
sum <- summary(model)
loc_se <- sum$se.theta[["location"]]
scale_se <- sum$se.theta[["scale"]]
shape_se <- sum$se.theta[["shape"]]

# extract AIC and BIC
aic <- sum$AIC
bic <- sum$BIC

